Convert a Hermes tracing profile to Chrome tracing profile without downloading from device
I have a somewhat aging react-native project running Flipper 0.125.0 that supports Hermes. For some reason, on every single platform, the command...
npx react-native profile-hermes ./cpuprofiles
...fails - it says that the cache directory is empty with no extra messaging. But this is not true, because I wrote another script that can absolutely successfully download the Hermes tracing profile to a local directory.
What I want to do is convert the downloaded profile from Hermes to Chrome without the download step which is very broken. But the react-native profile-hermes command doesn't support conversion without download. Does anyone else have a tip on how to just do the conversion on local files, skipping the broken device download?

This is not an answer to my original problem which I think would be a great tool for someone to create, but I did solve the original problem. When I created the react native app, I created it with the name com.appname. Eventually, I updated it to com.companyname.appname by only changing applicationID in build.gradle. This broke debugging but I was OK with it. What I didn't know is that this also broke the profile-hermes command. Upgrading to a newer RN+flipper version gave the error: "com.appname doesn't exist", and then when I find/replaced the old name with the new one, the OG CMD worked.
